# Primefaces 2.2.1 Refresh datatable and stackedBarChart

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am displaying my data in both the `stackedBarChart` and `dataTable` format in the same window.  I can specify in the `stackedBarChart` that the data is live and the refresh interval, but how do I get the datatable data to also update when the stackedBarChart data refreshes?

Do I have to write my own refresh java script and manually update both of my data representations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `<p:poll interval="3" update="votes" />` like in the showcase to update your chart you can try adding the id of the table to the update attribute like that `<p:poll interval="3"  update="votes, tableID"/>`

haven't tested... but sound reasonable